# Convergence of integral of a positive function implies the series converges as well

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is a function having the following properties:

- 1. Positive
- 2. Continuous
- 3. $\int f(x)dx$ converges

Then I think the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f(n)$ converges. I would reason that if $f(x)$ wasn't positive then this statement would be false. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I suspect there is a counterexample, so no. Indeed $f(n)$ does not need to converge to $0$ or anything else.  On the other hand, if $f(x)$ was also monotonic decreasing ...

Comment: You need monotonicity or something similar - think of a function that is $1/n$ at integer $n$ but which drops fast in between so the integral on the interval $[n,n+1]$ is $1/n^2$ say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not true. Draw a triangle with base $(n-\frac  1{n^{3}}, n+\frac  1{n^{3}})$ and height $n$. Using these traingles you get a  continuous non-negaive function $f$ whose intergal is finite but $f(n)=n$ for each $n$.  If you want the function to be strictly positive just add $e^{-|x|}$ to this function.

Explicit definition of $f$: $f(x)=n^{4}(x-n+\frac1  {n^{3}})$ for $n-\frac  1 {n^{3}} \leq x \leq n$, $f(x)=n^{4}(n+\frac 1  {n^{3}}-x)$ for $n \leq x \leq n+\frac  1 {n^{3}}$, $n=2,3,4...$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is not in any of these intervals.

Comment: But f here is not positive if n=1

Comment: I said $n=2,3,4...$ didn't I? @MAATHLOVER01